# problem in inserting the vlaues into database

Tags: iphone, sqlite

i was getting familiar with sqlite and try to insert the values into database but giving exception. tf1 and tf2 are object of textfield. here is my code:

```
@synthesize tf1, tf2, add, disp;
-(id)initApp

{
if(![super init])
        return nil;

    //DB stored in application bundle
    NSString *DBName = @"kbase.sqlite";
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:DBName];

    db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];
    [db setLogsErrors:TRUE];
    [db setTraceExecution:TRUE];

    if(![db open])
    {
        NSLog(@"Could not open Database");
        return 0;
    }

    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Database opened successfully");
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self initApp];
    [add addTarget:self action:@selector(insertButtonClicked:)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
    [disp addTarget:self action:@selector(displaytButtonClicked:)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
}


-(IBAction)insertButtonClicked :(id)sender
{ 
    NSLog(@"insert");
    NSLog(@"db.....%@",db);
    [db executeUpdate:@"insert into info values (?,?)", tf1.text, tf2.text];

    [self resignFirstResponder];

}

-(IBAction)displayButtonClicked:(id)sender

{
    NSString *str1 = tf2.text;
    NSString *returnResult = [[NSString alloc]init];
    FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:@"select name from info where rollno = 1"];

    while ([rs next])
    {
        returnResult = [rs stringForColumn:@"rollno"];
        [tf1 setText:returnResult];
        [tf2 setText:returnResult];
    }       
}
```

databse is opening successfully and controll terminate after printing insert
exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL executeQuery:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3d30ef0'
```

i am not able to configure the problem. plz help.

Comment: show the code of executeUpdate

Comment: As you can see, an NSURL object gets the query method. Can you dump the class name of the db before you fire your statements? And please post the code how you setup the db.

Comment: what are you doing in executeUpdate method?
Can you show the code?

Comment: @rakesh loves, @chetan bhalara: i have updated my code! plz chk out the code

Comment: @chetan : i used the sqlite manager to create bd and table!

Comment: @nick weawer: i am getting u? how to dump the class name of?

Comment: @nick: when i print the value of db, it diplays :ocalhost/Users/gauravmurghai/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simula­tor/User/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist in gdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think make your method

[db executeUpdate:@"insert into info values (?,?)" withValue1:tf1.text withValue2:tf2.text];

Instead of

[db executeUpdate:@"insert into info values (?,?)", tf1.text, tf2.text];

Comment: let me explain all. i have created database through sqlite manager and declare only column name "name","rollno". i dragged this database into my resources folder. so all it is giving exception

Answer (score 0):

it seems that `db` does not exist in this context. If `db` is a class variable, make sure it is not released somewhere else. Simply put an `NSLog(@"%@", db);` above the execution to test it.

Comment: db is the FMDatabase class object!

Comment: sorry its showing the path:localhost/Users/gauravmurghai/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/User/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist. i didnt put the calue in UITextField before!